# SQL GROUP BY HAVING issue

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2000, having

I have two tables of records that I need to find all of the matches.  The tables are based on different Primary Key identifiers, but the data points are exactly the same.  I need a fast query that can show me records that are duplicated from the first table to the second.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID INT, Value INT)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (ID INT, Value INT)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1, 500)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (2, 500)

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (3, 500)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (4, 500)

SELECT  MAX(x.T1ID)
        ,MAX(x.T2ID)
FROM    (
            SELECT  T1ID = t1.ID
                    ,T2ID = 0
                    ,t1.Value
            FROM    @Table1 t1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  T1ID = 0
                    ,T2ID = t2.ID
                    ,t2.Value
            FROM    @Table2 t2
        ) x
GROUP BY x.Value
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

The problem with this code is that it returns record 2 in table 1 correlated to record 4 in table 2.  I really need it to return record 1 in table 1 correlated to record 3 in table 2.  I tried the following:

```
SELECT  MIN(x.T1ID)
        ,MIN(x.T2ID)
FROM    (
            SELECT  T1ID = t1.ID
                    ,T2ID = 0
                    ,t1.Value
            FROM    @Table1 t1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  T1ID = 0
                    ,T2ID = t2.ID
                    ,t2.Value
            FROM    @Table2 t2
        ) x
GROUP BY x.Value
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

This code does not work either.  It returns 0,0.

Is there a way to return the MIN value greater than 0 for both tables?

Comment: Without changing much, I think you could simply replace the `0` placeholders with `NULL` placeholders (`T2ID = NULL`, `T1ID = NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

Might answer my own question.  This seems to work.  Are there any reasons why I would not do this?

```
SELECT  MIN(t1.ID)
        ,MIN(t2.ID)
FROM    @Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t1.Value = t2.Value
GROUP BY t1.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the records in table1 that have matches in table2 then

```
select *
from @Table1 T1
where exists (select * from @Table2 T2
where T1.ID=T2.ID 
-- you would put the complete join clause that defines a match here
)
```

Comment: I dont want to see all records that match, I need the minimum records that matches from both tables.  I think my answer does just that.